# Can't find data in MongoDB and use .then

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I try to create very simple authentication system. In my MongoDB database I have this data:

```json
{
  "__v": 0,
  "password": "4c1b9bb3405f53cf46731af89f07b01d1ffe974f944d81085cb962abc45ee9c3",
  "_id": "589f5ee85a3b61176c9d0a61"
}
```

Then I try to check it by these functions:

```javascript
router.post('/api/admin/login', (req, res) => {
    db.getRootToken(req.body).then(function(data) {
        if (data.error) {
            return res.status(403).send(data);
        } else {
            return res.status(200).send(data);
        }
    });
});

function getRootToken(data) {
    console.log(data.password);
    var password_sha256 = sha256(data.password);
    console.log(password_sha256);
    Root.findOne({ password: password_sha256 }, function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs.length);
        if (docs.length) {
            console.log("root found");
            return { token: password_sha256 };
        } else {
            console.log("root not found");
            return { error: "Incorrect password!" };
        }
    });
}
```

But when I try to use `/api/admin/login` with `{ "password" : "pa55word" }`,
I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "then" of undefined

Also, the app can't find any data, because this code returns "root not found", but hash function gives me `4c1b9bb3405f53cf46731af89f07b01d1ffe974f944d81085cb962abc45ee9c3` for "pa55word" which is equal to value in database.

Where are my errors and how can I fix them?

Comment: `getRootToken` needs to `return` a `Promise`

Comment: And you need `db.getRootToken = function (data) {...}` instead of `function getRootToken(data) {...}`

Comment: @4castle, how to do it in my case? I am newbie in js, sorry for stupid question

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using callback and find instead of findOne. Thanks for all!

Comment: Can you please show the code you used to fix it? This will make the answer more useful to future users.